# Issue reading googleapi response using jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I want to use jQuery function to fetch web service response but getting error 405 saying method not allowed . When I copy paste the same string in the web browser I get xml result without error. below is the code I am using

```
[
 var arr= new Array();
        var loopCounter = 0;
        alert("Before Ajax")
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=ajax&destination=toronto&region=ca&avoid=tolls&sensor=false",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                alert("I am working");
                $(xml).find('distance').each(function() {
                    arr[loopCounter] = $(this).find('text').text();
                    alert("Some Value Of Distance = "+arr[loopCounter]);
                    loopCounter += 1;
                });

            }
        });]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use is JSONP for cross domain requests:

> If the URL includes the string
>   "callback=?" (or similar, as defined
>   by the server-side API), the request
>   is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in
>   [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by the same origin policy, which means that you can only use Ajax to fetch a url with the same origin(include domain, port, protocal)

Comment: Can you please explain more i am new and din't understand how to solve the probolem.

Comment: @ molvi You can read the JavaScript API of Google Maps to know how to use the api in JS:http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/